# Preventing the user from entering javascript instead of a url for use in an href

Tags: javascript, href, sanitization

I need to stop the user putting javascript into what should be a link field. I know I could just check for "javascript:" at the start of the url they enter, but I was wondering if there was some way I could construct the `<a>` tag to force it to treat the href as an address? I feel like this would be a better solution, as people are always finding ways to get around basic checks.

Comment: To what end? Is this field being sent up to a server? If so, the validation should occur at that end really. Anyone can monkey around with the client to make it do whatever they want.

Comment: It's to stop users crafting XSS attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A funny solution (and very effective if you ask me), is to put `http://` in front of urls that don't already start with it. This is a sketch of what I mean:

```
if(url.slice(0,"http://".length) !== "http://" && url.slice(0,"https://".length) !== "https://") {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better whitelist than blacklist and check for http(s) protocol, I'd guess.

Comment: That's what I thought. I might just make it a requirement that the URL start with http or https

Answer (score 1):

You could always prepend the http:// or https:// protocol. May require a replace to remove any existing http or https.

Even if you have

```
http://javascript:alert('test');
```

the javascript will not run.

Answer (score 1):

First you should recognize that the browser can be manipulated into submitting whatever the user wants, so client-side validation is neither necessary nor sufficient, just convenient (to the user).

Given that, an easy process comes to mind:

- Enforce that every URL is absolute by requiring a protocol spec at the beginning of the URL.
- Enforce that the protocol is one of {http, https}.

Try this:

```
function validateUrl(value) {
  return value.match(/^(http|https):\/\//) != null;
}

if(validateUrl(inputField.value)) {
  // value is acceptable
} else {
  // value is not an acceptable URL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure HTML way of forcing the  tag to treat the href as a URL.

The only thing (I know of) that you can do is check for javascript in the href attribute.